# customize share text for G+, FB, and LinkedIn, WITHOUT using OG meta tags

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph, linkedin-api, google-plus

Twitter has a beautiful share API.  If I want to customize text, I just include it in the URL I'm linking to:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" 
   class="twitter-share-button" 
   data-text="whoa, check out this SUPER-EASY CUSTOMIZED TWEET TEXT!" 
   data-via="foo">
   Tweet
</a>
```

My question is whether there is a way to do this with Facebook, Google Plus, and LinkedIn.

I want to be able to do this *without* having to put og meta tags in the link target.  Basically instead of the link target having knowledge of the message, I want the share button itself to have that knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: For FB: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to populate your pages with metadata to describe them to non-human systems including search engines, social networks, screen readers etc. For Google+, you have your choice methods: Schema.org metadata, OpenGraph, or simple meta names/descriptions. You can read more about how to populate snippets from your site at https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/